# Markov process with Weibull transition rate

Tags: markov-chains, exponential-distribution, transition-matrix

A discreet-time Markov process for which a transition probability matrix $P$ is independent of time can be represented, or approximated, with a continuous-time Markov chain (CMTC) with constant transition rates using exponential probability distributions. How do we obtain a continuous-time representation when the transition rates are not constant but depend on time a given by Weibull distribution?

For constant rates, we have for CMTC

$$P(t) = \exp(Qt)$$

(as a result of solving the forward equation) where $Q$ is the transition rate matrix with entries related to the exponential distribution parameters.

The above expression for $P(t)$ would probably not longer be valid if the rates are not constant in time.  Is there a known solution to this "generalized" problem (since exponential is a special case of Weibull for k=1)?

**Add 1**

The forward equation for $P(t)$ is given by

$$
\frac{\partial P(t)}{\partial t} = P(t)Q(t).
$$

If I understand it correctly, then the transition rate matrix $Q$ contains on the off-diagonal hazard rates of the competing underlying processes representing CTMC. If these processes follow exponential distribution, then these rates are constant and $Q$ is independent of time. However, if these hazard rates follow Weibull distribution then, I suppose, the off-diagonal elements of $Q$ are given by

$$
q_{i,j} = \beta_{i,j} k_{i,j} t^{k_{i,j}-1}.
$$

It seems to me that with these form of the hazard rates, it is still posible to solve analytically the forward equation to get

$$
P(t) = \exp(A(t))
$$

where

$$
(A)_{i,j} =  \beta_{i,j} t^{k_{i,j}}.
$$

I don't really know if this is correct or how to go from here to find, for example, limiting distribution.

**Add 2**

The system I am considering has 4 states: 1 "alive" and 3 "dead", so the transition probability matrix looks something like

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    p_{0,0}(t) & p_{0,1}(t) & p_{0,2}(t) & p_{0,3}(t) \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 &  1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

so, if I am not mistaken, we have the following system of ODE's (assuming that the forward equation still holds in this case):

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    p^\prime_{0,0}  = p_{0,0} \cdot q_{0,0}(t) \\
    p^\prime_{0,1} = p_{0,1} \cdot q_{0,1}(t) \\
    p^\prime_{0,2} = p_{0,2} \cdot q_{0,2}(t) \\
    p^\prime_{0,3} = p_{0,3} \cdot q_{0,3}(t) \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Is this correct? Would this system be solvable for $q_{0,i}(t) : i>0 $ given by Weibull hazard rates?

**Add 3**

If the above is correct, then with $q_{0,i}(t) = \beta_i k_i t^{k_i - 1} : i>0$, I get that

$$
\frac{d p_{0,0}(t)}{dt} = p_{0,0}(t) \left(- \sum_{i=1}^3 \beta_i k_i t^{k_i - 1} \right)
$$

which, with $p_{0,0}(t=0) = 1$, gives

$$
p_{0,0}(t) = \exp \left(- \sum_{i=1}^3 \beta_i t^{k_i} \right)
$$

and

$$
p_{0,i}(t) = \int_0^t \beta_i k_i s^{k_i - 1} \exp \left(- \sum_{i=1}^3 \beta_i s^{k_i} \right) ds + c_i
$$

If we had $k_i = k \; \forall \; i$, then, with $p_{0,i}(t=0) = 0 : i>0$, the above can be integrated to get

$$
p_{0,i}(t) = \frac{\beta_i}{\sum_{i=1}^3 \beta_i} - \frac{\beta_i}{\sum_{i=1}^3 \beta_i} \exp \left(- t^k \sum_{i=1}^3 \beta_i \right)
$$

but, alas, the $k_i$s are not the same.

**Add 4**

I mostly interested in the probabilities for $t \le 1$ and I have $\beta_i < 1 \; \forall \; i$, so I am thinking of approximating the exponential  $\exp \left(- \sum_{i=1}^3 \beta_i t^{k_i} \right)$ with a second-degree polynomial in $\sum_{i=1}^3 \beta_i t^{k_i}$.  I am thinking about using something like shifted Legendre polynomials on [0, 1], but my upper limit may be less than 1 (actually, more than $-\sum_i \beta_i$), so might need to look into adjusting the coefficients for this.  I am also not sure if calculating the coefficients for the expansion of $\exp(x)$ and substituting $x=\sum_{i=1}^3 \beta_i t^{k_i}$ will give the same approximation as calculating the coefficients on $\exp \left(- \sum_{i=1}^3 \beta_i t^{k_i} \right)$ directly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing, exactly. Can you give a small example of your "ground truth" model? Just a two state example should suffice.

Comment: @Ian  Thank you for your comment.  I am trying to figure out how to represent a CMTC when the transition rates in $Q$ are functions of time, specifically $Q_{i,j} = \beta_{i} k_{i} t^{k-1}$.

Comment: You mean you're trying to cook up the analogue of the "DTMC + holding times" description for a given CTMC with time-dependent rates? I ask because it sounds like your "ground truth" in the question is a DTMC and you're trying to use a CTMC approximation.

Comment: That said, in the special case where $Q_{i,j}(t)/Q_{i,i}(t)$ doesn't depend on $t$, you still have the same DTMC as in the time-homogeneous case, and you're only left to model the holding times.

Comment: @Ian  Yes, I am looking for a description of CTMC with time-dependent rates (specifically, with Weibull hazard rates). Not quite sure what you mean by "ground truth" but I have a process which is sampled with daily frequency, so I suppose it could be thought of as both a DTMC and/or CTMC with daily observations.  In any case, how do I go about finding the probability matrix $P(t)$ for CTMC with time-dependent rates?

Comment: @Ian  I have added some more details to the question. Hope it makes it clearer. Thank you

Comment: I say "ground truth" to make the distinction between what you consider to be true (or at least would be happy if you could fully understand) and what could serve as a good approximation of the truth. For example if you have a process that is "really" transitioning at random times and you simply sample it periodically, your ground truth is a CTMC even though your samples are discrete in time.

Comment: (Cont.) In fact in this situation there is really no DTMC present even though you could in principle draw trajectories and fit those trajectories to a DTMC (which might be a good approximation if your samples are sufficiently close together).

Comment: Anyway, the question I have now is, are you saying that the rates increase *as you spend more time at the same state*, or that they actually do increase *over time in absolute terms*? In particular, does the total holding time at state $i$ have the same distribution no matter when you arrived at $i$ or not? These two things are very different because in the latter case you have an explicit $Q(t)$ so that you can at least formally solve the FPE/FKE, whereas in the former case you don't.

Comment: @Ian  Thank you for your comments. If I understood your question correctly, then the situation I am considering is known as a non-homogenous CTMC where transition probabilities are a function of the "absolute" time since the start of  the system, and not semi-Markov process where transition probabilities depend on the time since entering a state ("local" time). Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it does. In that case in attempting to solve the FPE/FKE there is a question as to whether the $Q$ matrices commute or not. The situation is significantly simpler if they do. If the $k_{i,j}$ are all the same then they absolutely do but otherwise they probably don't.

Comment: @Ian  Not sure I understand what you are asking here? There is only one matrix $Q$.  Or do you mean if $Q(t)$ commutes with $Q(s)$?  Why does this matter and how do I verify this for Weibull hazard rates? Thank you

Comment: I mean whether $Q(t)$ commutes with $Q(s)$. It is a lot easier to solve a time-dependent linear system of ODEs when the coefficient matrices at different times commute. Specifically in this case the analogue of $e^{Qt}$ is $e^{\int_0^t Q(s) ds}$. But most likely this condition doesn't hold in your setting unless you have an unusually special relationship between the $k_{i,j}$.

Comment: @Ian  No, I don't believe they commute for un-equal values of $k$.  So, how could I proceed?  I would have thought that this type of problem had been well studied by now, but I haven't found any resources on it yet.

Comment: @Ian  The process I am looking at is fairly simple with 4 states, 3 of which are absorbing.  I gave further details in the question - perhaps in this case it is possible to find the solution?

Comment: Oh, in that case it is very easy to manage. WLOG $p_0(0)=1$ and the others are $0$, then $dp_0/dt = -\sum_{j \neq i} p_0(t) q_{0,j}(t)$ and $dp_k/dt=p_0(t) q_{0,k}(t)$. So the first equation is just a single first order linear equation and then the others are just solved by integration once you know $p_0(t)$.

Comment: @Ian  Unfortunately, I don't think the integration has analytical solutions.  I wonder, however, if it is still possible to obtain limiting distribution without the full knowledge of the transient one?  Would it be something like the ration of hazard rates integrated over time?

Comment: No, I don't think you can do anything in particular. The equilibrium probabilities look like $\int_0^\infty c_j t^{n_j} \exp \left ( -\sum_k \frac{c_k}{n_k+1} t^{n_k+1} \right ) dt$ and that doesn't simplify in any convenient way. But this class of integrals are extremely inexpensive to evaluate numerically.

Comment: The intuitive reason why this isn't as easy as you seem to think it might be is because you have to weight each of your rate comparisons by the likelihood that the absorption event is taking place at the time when the comparison is made. Imagine a case where one rate is 100 and the other is 1 for 100 time units and then they trade places and never trade back. Most of the history has the second rate being larger but almost all the trajectories absorbed before they traded places, so the probability of absorbing into the first state is going to be just a hair less than 0.99.

Comment: You could do the kind of polynomial-type calculation that you're talking about in Edit 4 using chebfun in Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario with

$$Q=\begin{bmatrix} -(r_1(t)+r_2(t)+r_3(t)) & r_1(t) & r_2(t) & r_3(t) \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

you can solve the forward equation mostly explicitly. Assuming you start with $p_0=1$ (it is easy enough to adjust if this isn't the case), you have $p_0(t)=\exp \left ( -\int_0^t \sum_{i=1}^3 r_i(s) \, ds \right )$. For the others you have $p_i(t)=\int_0^t r_i(s) p_0(s) \, ds=\int_0^t r_i(s) \exp \left ( -\int_0^s \sum_{j=1}^3 r_j(u) \, du \right ) \, ds$. In your situation this results in some integrals that will need numerical evaluation, even for getting the equilibrium probabilities, except under some extremely restrictive assumptions about the exponents $k_{0,j}$. But this is a pretty inexpensive class of integrals to evaluate, since the $r_j$ can be analytically integrated themselves.

That said, you can make a little bit of analytical progress in your situation by changing variables in the outer integral to $v:=\int_0^s r_i(u) \, du=\beta_{0,i} s^{k_{0,i}}$. Then you have $\int_0^s r_j(u) du = \beta_{0,j} s^{k_{0,j}}=\beta_{0,j} \beta_{0,i}^{-\frac{k_{0,j}}{k_{0,i}}} v^{ \frac{k_{0,j}}{k_{0,i}}}$.

Therefore you end up with

$$p_i(t)=\int_0^{t'} \exp \left ( -v -\sum_{j \neq i} \beta_{0,j} \beta_{0,i}^{-\frac{k_{0,j}}{k_{0,i}}} v^{ \frac{k_{0,j}}{k_{0,i}}} \right ) dv$$

where $t'=\int_0^t r_i(s) ds$.

You still can't generally evaluate that analytically, but it does standardize the situation in some sense, especially if you are seeking the stationary distribution (so that $t'$ is just $\infty$).

Comment: Thank you for your post, Ian.  Which numerical integration scheme do you think would be most appropriate here given the form of the integrand?  Some kind of a quadrature, I guess?  Thank you

Comment: @Confounded I can think of three suggestions. 1. Change variables so that the bounds are finite (for example you could use $e^{-t}$ as your variable) and then use a black box tool like integral() in Matlab. Be warned that this approach might create an integrable singularity. 2. Change variables as I described in the answer, then truncate each of them at $\log(1/\varepsilon)$ where $\varepsilon$ is your error tolerance. 3. Change variables like I described in the question and then use Gauss-Laguerre quadrature.